# Global Transaction Scope for Nested Transactions

Tags: c#, .net, transactions

Currently, I have methods in various classes that use transaction scope, and that some times make calls to each other to share operations, I manange my code like this (the code is just an example similar to my real implementation)

```cs
public class Father
{
    public void CreateFather()
    {
        using (TransactionScope mainScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            Son son = new Son();
            //Some database operations
            son.CreateSon();
            mainScope.Complete();
        }
    }
}

public class Son
{
    public void CreateSon()
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //Some database operations,
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid writing

```
using (TransactionScope mainScope = new TransactionScope()){
}
```

in every method and create a global class that shares transaction? Or is there any way to create an implicit transaction that executes when using classes from my DAL, that handles complete and dispose. Something like

```cs
public class Father
{
    public void CreateFather()
    {
        //some transaction code
        GlobalTransaction.Run(); //Start transaction
        Son son = new Son();
        son.CreateSon(); //If CreateSon() fails, father transaction rolls back
    }
}

public class Son
{
    public void CreateSon()
    {
         //some transaction code
         GlobalTransaction.Run(); //Uses current transaction, in this case from CreateFather()
    }
}
```

The application is an ASP.Net one.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
using (TransactionScope mainScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required)){
}
```

This option says, that if there is a transaction new scope will support it and does not create new one. More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
Also, it's a default value for `TransactionScope`, so if call it like this everywhere, you will not have problems.